# Blocking Internet access for a particular user

Tags: user-account, internet

On a MacBook that connects to the Internet via wi-fi, how can I prevent one user account from accessing the Internet (with no effect on other accounts)?

Note: i want to block ALL access, not just Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Parental Controls preference pane? A lot of options there, none specifically to block all internet access, but you can get to the same place by only allowing access to applications without it.

1. From the **Apple** menu, choose **System Preferences**.
2. From the **View** menu, choose **Parental Controls**.

More info on the Apple web site: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2900?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

A hardware-based solution to limit ***all*** access would be to use only a USB ethernet or WiFi adapter to connect to your Internet service.  Disable all built-in adapters, and only give physical access to the USB adapter to authorized users.

Comment: Actually, this is a MacBook, which connects to the Internet via wi-fi. I've added these details to the question.

Comment: I think you should be able to disable the built-in WiFi adapter and use a USB adapter instead.  I don't have a USB WiFi to test this with currently, but it's something I've done in the past.